# How can i to create base class for extend to another class?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How can i to create base class for extend to another class

```
class BaseCustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = None
    list_display =  [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()]
    search_fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()]
```

use like this

```
class BaseCustomModelAdmin(BaseCustomModelAdmin):
    model = Person
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Base(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =  [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()]
    search_fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()]


@admin.register(Person)
class PersonModelAdmin(Base):
    pass
```

Comment: i tried 'NameError: name 'model' is not defined'

Comment: import your model